# Alfresco edit in microsoft office integration

Tags: office365, alfresco, alfresco-enterprise

I have problems using the "edit in Microsoft Office" functionality of an Alfresco Enterprise 5.2.6.
I use both firefox (70.0) or chrome (78) on a Windows 10 Machine (winver 1903) and I have Microsoft Office 365 Business (version 1910) activated on my machine.

When I click on the share action the office app (Word or Excel) opens but then it says it can't download the content.

The same problem is on my production server, where is also installed an ssl certificate and a nginx reverse proxy.

What do I miss?
Do I need the [alfresco office service](https://docs.alfresco.com/aos1.1/concepts/aos-user.html) amp file? Do I need a particular alfresco-global.properties configuration?

Comment: Are you using 32 bit or 64 bit versions of Windows 10 and office?

Comment: 64 bit for windows, and 64 bit for office

Comment: AOS is a paid-for feature, so your best bet is just to raise an Alfresco Support ticket. You're paying them, they're the experts, AOS is fiddly, use their help you pay for!

Comment: We encounter the very same problem, but it's not systematic. 


AOS is not a paid feature (present in Docker community version).

What I have found so far is that O365 makes a lot of POSTs to /alfresco/aos/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll with the Alfresco returns an HTTP 401 (most probablely because there is no JSESSION_ID nor Authorization Header.

After posting a lot of them and getting a lot of http 401 (acces denied), the O365 suddenly abandons and ask the file. Alfresco gives him. So the file is really available in O365 but can't be uploaded afterward if we modify and save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a real "general" answer, but in my case it was an Nginx configuration problem. The reverse proxy did block the public url to be exposed.